# Display stored value of field for choice in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django model with a choice:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (A, 'Plan Type A'),
        (B, 'Plan Type B'),
    )
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the admin list view for this model I want to display the stored value: `'A'` or `'B'` instead of the "display" value of the choice: `'Plan Type A'` or `'Plan Type B'`. When my `admin.py` looks like this:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('project_type', 'name')
    pass
admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

I get the display value of the choice (I guess the admin is trying to be helpful and calling `get_project_type_choices_display` for me or something). How can I force it to return the stored value?

Comment: Simplest would be to add a differently named property/method to your model that simply returns `project_type` and use that.

Comment: Yes, I could definitely do that. It was just a surprise to have the admin resolve the display value for me.

Comment: That's what the choice tuples are for after all. The display value is the one assumed by django to be the one best read by humans.

Comment: True. My thinking here is that the list_display doesn't leave much room, so I want my abbreviated version. More commonly, I suppose its an integer which wouldn't be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callable for that. Add it to the model and add

```
  def project_type_value(self):
      return ("%s" % (self.project_type))
  project_type_value.short_description = 'Project type'
```

In admin:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('project_type_value', 'name')

admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```